# Change color of Icon when text is in input - vue.js

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I use the font-awesome search icon in my project. Actually, I do it in vue.js. The font-awesome-icon is in the input component and I want to change the color of this icon to yellow when the input is active and what's more - also when there are some already typed text in the input.

```
 <font-awesome-icon :class="isEmpty ? 'white-color' : 'yellow-color'" icon="search" />
```

Earlier I had css to make this effect, but it didn't handle problem - when some text is already typed, but there is no focus on input. It was like that:

```
&{
svg {
   color: yellow;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
<font-awesome-icon :class="{'white-color' : isEmpty, 'yellow-color': !isEmpty }" icon="search" />
```

and having the stylings as

```
.white-color {
  color: white
}
.yellow-color {
  color: yellow
}
```

ELSE
you can use computed property

```
<font-awesome-icon :style="getColor" icon="search" />
```

and your computed property should be

```
computed: {
 getColor() {
   if(this.isEmpty) {
     return {
        color: 'white'
     }
   }
  return {
   color: 'yellow'
  }
 }
}
```